# Dont want my cshrc to execute on login

Tags: csh, su

On unix I am working as say user X, and I want to login to user Y from X. Now issue is that I dont want Y's cshrc (or any other login script) to run while I login to his user name. I vaguely remember there used to be a way to do so, something like execute "su" command with some option for not running login scripts, but none of them is working. Can somebody please help ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running this

```
su - user_y
```

will login as user y and run the startup scripts, whatever they are.
Running this

```
su user_y
```

will make you "become" user y but will not run the startup scripts.  This is not cshell specific.